# Import XML to object list

Tags: c#, xml, list, object

I am currently experiencing an issue trying to import my XML elements into a list of type Books. I am receiving an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error on this piece of code:

```
mybook.Title = p.Element("title").Value;
```

Am I referencing the XML element improperly or is it some other simple matter? I have googled for hours on end through endless solutions and topics and can not get over this last hurdle.

For simplicity, here is the code in one file:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(appPath, "Books.xml"));

        Console.WriteLine(GetBooks());
    }

    public class Books
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<Books> GetBooks()
    {
        XDocument doc = LinqToXml.XmlHelper.GetPlantDocument();
        var xmlBooks = doc.Descendants("catalog");
        List<Books> someBooks = new List<Books>();

        foreach (var p in xmlBooks)
        {
            Books mybook = new Books();
            mybook.Title = p.Element("title").Value;
            someBooks.Add(mybook);
        }
        return someBooks;
    }
}
```

This is the contents of the XML file:

http://pastebin.com/ZVmWqRT1

Please note that this is indeed a homework project. I am not looking for a direct answer necessarily as I am a giant hint or two.

Comment: Hint:  View the elements as a path.  You have a collection of all the elements under "catalog", but you're trying to skip ahead and get "title" without completing the path.

Comment: Another hint:  What you want is to grab the collection of "Book" elements and their children.  If you start with `doc.Descendants("Book") you might find it easier to get the "Title", rather than grabbing all the children under "Catalog".

Comment: Ah. That was something I was trying earlier, my mistake. This issue occurs with the ID as well as other elements such as title.

Comment: Final (for now) hint:  You can use LINQ extensions methods to incorporate the List `someBooks`.   In your LINQ query, create the type of Book and and at the end of the query add `.ToList()`.

Comment: "id" is an attribute, not an element, so you'll need to access it with `Attribute("id")`.

Comment: Unable to see your XML file, link is showing blank.

Comment: Another option is to annotate `class Book` members with XmlElement, XmlAttribute and use [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("c:\\hello.xml");

List<Books> lstBooks=doc.Elements("book").Select(x=>
new Books
{
        ID=x.Attribute("id").Value,
        Name=x.Element("author").Value,
        Title =x.Element("title").Value,
        Price =decimal.Parse(x.Element("price").Value),
        PublishDate =Convert.ToDateTime(x.Element("publish_date").Value),
        Description=x.Element("description").Value
}
).ToList(); 

//lstBooks now contain all the books
foreach(Books b in lstBooks)
{
         b.ID;
         b.Name;...........
}
```